# Silverlight get XAP file date

Tags: silverlight

can somebody please show me how to return the file modified date from the Silverlight XAP file that the client has just opened. I'm adding a tooltip that shows this date so that I can verify which version of XAP the client is running.

Thanks.

Comment: You can get Fileinfo from web side normally. But you can get running assembly version by reflection in Bus side.What you need exactly ?If you want to check the version is invalid status then reload new xap there are solutions in stackoverflow. I think you should use RunningAssembly version to learn client app version.Not file modified date.

Answer (score 0):

Because this project is in a state of flux, I'm doing updates every few hours. Currently there are about 3-4 users/testers but they can leave their browser open for the day. I have a poll function and I need this to send the date/time of the local XAP file back to the WCF server so it can let it know if an update is available. If so, the user will see a popup msg and prompt them to hit refresh.

I believe the RunningAssembly version would need to be updated by myself and is not automatically incremented with each build? If it is, then RunningAssembly is the way to go...

Thanks for the response..